Why are my C# Azure SDK binding redirects not working?
I am making a DLL extension that uses the Azure SDK libraries in .NET framework 4.6 to an existing program.
I had the program developers compile the program adding a reference to my DLL earlier, however, after i compiled it and run it, it appears that it attempts to load two different versions of Azure.Core at the same time: 1.42, the one which is referenced in the project, and 1.39 the one which Azure.ResourceManager specifies in the nuget package view in Visual Studio ">=1.39". The same will happen for Azure.ResourceManager 1.12 and 1.13 (likely referenced by one of the ResourceManager submodules).
My understanding was that with binding redirects, this shouldn't happen because at runtime the 1.42 or whatever version i specified should be the only one marked as valid.
What I tried:

Placed ALL the libraries in the build folder of my extension in the folder of the program executable
I double checked the app.config, made sure that binding redirects were enabled and correctly pointed (including the public key) and recompiled multiple times
adding the binding redirects to machine.config on the computer
running it on a different computer with the same program (same issue)
changing Azure.Core/RM dll version (the error swaps versions as well)

I don't know what else to try at this point.
EDIT: here's the app.config contents:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.9" newVersion="6.0.0.9" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.42.0.0" newVersion="1.42.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.1" newVersion="6.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.ResourceManager" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.13.0.0" newVersion="1.13.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" /></startup></configuration>



Can you share the app.config?

@RyanThomas yep, added it to the post.

Since the project involves a .NET Framework application (4.6.1) using libraries that are targeting .NET Standard (like the Azure SDK libraries), binding redirects don’t exist in .NET Standard or .NET Core, but .NET Framework uses them to resolve assembly version conflicts.

If you use the new PackageReference system in the project

Adding the properties:
<Target Name="ForceGenerationOfBindingRedirects"
        AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"
        BeforeTargets="GenerateBindingRedirects"
        Condition="'$(AutoGenerateBindingRedirects)' == 'true'">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- This ensures binding redirects are generated for libraries as well -->
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

There need to be set in a target, since common targets only set it to true, do not set to false.
Binder Logs:
Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/11/2024 @ 2:20:00 PM)

Bind result: Succeeded.

Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
--- A detailed success log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Azure.Core, Version=1.42.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/MyApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyApp.exe
Calling assembly : Azure.ResourceManager, Version=1.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/MyApp/Azure.Core.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful.
LOG: Binding policy redirected assembly version.
LOG: Binding redirect applied to load version: 1.42.0.0.
LOG: Final path was loaded: file:///C:/Program Files/MyApp/Azure.Core.DLL.

=== Bind result for Azure.ResourceManager ===
LOG: DisplayName = Azure.ResourceManager, Version=1.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
LOG: Assembly download was successful.
LOG: Binding redirect applied to load version: 1.13.0.0.

